# How to create UILabel programmatically using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uilabel

How do I create a `UILabel` programmatically using Swift in Xcode 6?

I have started with a new "Single View Application" in Xcode 6 and selected Swift for this project. I have my files `AppDelegate.swift` and `ViewController.swift` and I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: I suggest you start your study here: [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/index.html) and work your way to [Raywenderlich Tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/)

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Creating a UILabel programmatically in Swift 3+:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "I'm a test label"

    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Comment: You should not hard code the labels frame - what happens when text changes or text gets localized and changes the number of characters?

Comment: You can also check this blog that describes programmatically adding UITextField, UITextView and UILabel:
http://webindream.com/how-to-change-ui-elements-programmatically/

Comment: @iSuresh how do you know that CGPoint(x:160, y: 285) is going to be center for the model they're using?

Comment: But how to set up a UILabel that adjusts its width to the content?

Comment: @rommex To do so, call **label.sizeToFit()**.

Comment: **Swift5.1** var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 284)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.text = "I'm a test label"
    self.view.addSubview(label)

Answer (score 28):

Here is the correct code for Swift 3, with comments for instructional purposes:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // CGRectMake has been deprecated - and should be let, not var
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))

    // you will probably want to set the font (remember to use Dynamic Type!)
    label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)

    // and set the text color too - remember good contrast
    label.textColor = .black

    // may not be necessary (e.g., if the width & height match the superview)
    // if you do need to center, CGPointMake has been deprecated, so use this
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 284)

    // this changed in Swift 3 (much better, no?)
    label.textAlignment = .center

    label.text = "I am a test label"

    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gourav - hope it helped

Answer (score 17):

Just to add onto the already great answers, you might want to add multiple labels in your project so doing all of this (setting size, style etc) will be a pain. To solve this, you can create a separate UILabel class.

```
  import UIKit

  class MyLabel: UILabel {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeLabel()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeLabel()
    }

    func initializeLabel() {

        self.textAlignment = .left
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Halvetica", size: 17)
        self.textColor = UIColor.white

    }

}
```

To use it, do the following

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

     var myLabel: MyLabel()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          myLabel = MyLabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2, width: 100, height: 20))
          self.view.addSubView(myLabel)
     }


}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Comment: Thank you man, I have a question, if I want to pass a string to `self.text` inside a class to iniciate like this: `myLabel = MyLabel(string: "text")`

Comment: I just find out how, using your class and calling like this: `myLabel.text  = "text"`

Answer (score 17):

Create `UILabel` view outside `viewDidLoad` class and then add that view to your main view in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
lazy var myLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "This is label view."
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    return label
}()
```

And then add that `view` in `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(myLabel)
    
    // Set its constraint to display it on screen
    myLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  200).isActive = true
    myLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: @I Love Coding, can you please explain about your code. [lazy var myLabel: UILabel = { }() ]. It will helpful a lot. Thank you ....

Comment: @iOS When you create variable as `lazy var variable_name  = ""` it will not consume your memory unless that variable is called by your app. If that property is not used then it will never execute.

Comment: Then we will create all variables as lazy in our project for better performance. Am I right?

Comment: @iOS yeah! Better use that variable type in your app for better performance. Also, you should be able to aware of Thread as well for better performance.

Comment: thank you. This really helped me with the concept of using `lazy`

Answer (score 16):

Swift 4.X and Xcode 10

```
let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 230, height: 21))
lbl.textAlignment = .center //For center alignment
lbl.text = "This is my label fdsjhfg sjdg dfgdfgdfjgdjfhg jdfjgdfgdf end..."
lbl.textColor = .white
lbl.backgroundColor = .lightGray//If required
lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)

//To display multiple lines in label
lbl.numberOfLines = 0 //If you want to display only 2 lines replace 0(Zero) with 2.
lbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping //Word Wrap
// OR
lbl.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping //Charactor Wrap

lbl.sizeToFit()//If required
yourView.addSubview(lbl)
```

If you have multiple labels in your class use extension to add properties.

```
//Label 1
let lbl1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 230, height: 21))
lbl1.text = "This is my label fdsjhfg sjdg dfgdfgdfjgdjfhg jdfjgdfgdf end..."
lbl1.myLabel()//Call this function from extension to all your labels
view.addSubview(lbl1)

//Label 2
let lbl2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 150, width: 230, height: 21))
lbl2.text = "This is my label fdsjhfg sjdg dfgdfgdfjgdjfhg jdfjgdfgdf end..."
lbl2.myLabel()//Call this function from extension to all your labels
view.addSubview(lbl2)

extension UILabel {
    func myLabel() {
        textAlignment = .center
        textColor = .white
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        numberOfLines = 0
        lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can create a label using the code below. Updated.

```
let yourLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
yourLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 200, height: 21)
yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
yourLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
yourLabel.text = "test label"
self.view.addSubview(yourLabel)
```

Comment: I would add `yourLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` so you can move your view with constraints

Answer (score 9):

Another answer in Swift 3:

```
let myLabel = UILabel()
myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
myLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
myLabel.textAlignment = .center
myLabel.text = "myLabel!!!!!"
self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
```

Answer (score 6):

Create label in swift 4

```
 let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "Hello this my label"

    //To set the color
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    label.textColor = UIColor.black

    //To set the font Dynamic
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Regular", size: 20.0)

    //To set the system font
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)

    //To display multiple lines
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping //Wrap the word of label
    label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping //Wrap the charactor of label

    label.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative using a closure to separate out the code into something a bit neater using Swift 4:

```
class theViewController: UIViewController {

    /** Create the UILabel */
    var theLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.numberOfLines = 3
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 22)
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        /** Add theLabel to the ViewControllers view */
        view.addSubview(theLabel)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        /* Set the frame when the layout is changed */
        theLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                y: 0,
                                width: view.frame.width - 30,
                                height: 24)
    }
}
```

As a note, attributes for `theLabel` can still be changed whenever using functions in the VC. You're just setting various defaults inside the closure and minimizing clutter in functions like `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Beautiful technique...but it's not working for me in Xcode 9.4.1 ... unless I specify the frame somewhere in the computed value, whether in the constructor (`UILabel(frame:)`) or elsewhere in the block (`label.frame=`). Any later setting of the frame (e.g., in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`) caused the label not to appear.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10. Somewhere in ViewController:

```
private lazy var debugInfoLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    yourView.addSubview(label)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: suggestionView.centerXAnchor),
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: suggestionView.centerYAnchor, constant: -100),
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)])
    return label
}()
```

...

Using:

```
debugInfoLabel.text = debugInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.text = "My label"
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Try above code in ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10
Initialize label before viewDidLoad.

```
lazy var topLeftLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "TopLeft"
    return label
}()
```

In viewDidLoad add label to the view and apply constraints.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(topLeftLabel)
    topLeftLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    topLeftLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
}
```