# Aligning text inside custom drawing

Tags: ios, swift, text, alignment, drawing

I'm doing custom drawing in view. It basically just draws a circle. I need text to appear in the middle of that circle. I tried using stringToDraw method, but it aligns my text to the frame origination point. Is there a way to align?

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x:bounds.size.width/2,y:bounds.size.height/2)

        let halfSize:CGFloat = min( bounds.size.width/2, bounds.size.height/2)
        let desiredLineWidth:CGFloat = 1    // your desired value
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(

            arcCenter: arcCenter,
            radius: CGFloat( halfSize - (1/2) ),
            startAngle: CGFloat(0),
            endAngle:CGFloat(CGFloat.pi * 2),
            clockwise: true)




        circlePath.lineWidth = desiredLineWidth
        circlePath.stroke()


        let stringToDraw = "Text" as NSString 
        let rectToDraw = bounds 
        stringToDraw.draw(in: rectToDraw) 






    }
```

Comment: look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24081887/4468859

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using labels solved my problem:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x:bounds.size.width/2,y:bounds.size.height/2)
        // drawRingFittingInsideView(arccenter: arcCenter)
        let halfSize:CGFloat = min( bounds.size.width/2, bounds.size.height/2)
        let desiredLineWidth:CGFloat = 1    // your desired value
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(

            arcCenter: arcCenter,
            radius: CGFloat( halfSize - (1/2) ),
            startAngle: CGFloat(0),
            endAngle:CGFloat(CGFloat.pi * 2),
            clockwise: true)
        collisionPath = circlePath



        circlePath.lineWidth = desiredLineWidth
        circlePath.stroke()


        label.frame = bounds
        label.text = "AA"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.drawText(in: bounds)



    }
```