# How to link two view controllers to a programmatically created table view?

Tags: swift, storyboard, tableview, segue

Sorry for my bad English.

I want this: When someone click in a cell it opens in another view controller.

I created the table view programmatically.

```
import UIKit
class BibleBooksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

private let myArray: NSArray = ["Gênesis", "Êxodo", "Levitico"]
private var myTableView: UITableView!
var bibleArray = BibleBooksMock().booksArray

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let barHeight: CGFloat =
UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
    let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
    let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height

    myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: 
displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))
    myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: 
"MyCell")
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
Int) -> Int {
    return bibleArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
-> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: 
indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(bibleArray[indexPath.row].title)"
    return cell
 }
}
```

The output is this:

[image: The code output img from the code]

The iOS version is 12.1
The swift version is 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `BibleBooksViewController`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let chapter = bibleArray[indexPath.row]
    var vc = ChapterViewController()
    vc.chapterName = chapter.title
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

And define this controller:

```
class ChapterViewController: UIViewController {

    var chapterName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = chapterName

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

}
```

More about `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview).

Comment: " Cannot convert value of type 'ChapterViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController' "

Comment: It goes to a black screen is this right ?

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira yeah that seems right. You can update the controller's view background color. See my updated answer. Also, do you still get the error you mentioned at first?

Comment: Well, that first error is because I misspelled chapter.title.

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira look at my updated answer. In short, add `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white` to `ChapterViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Ok, but i am trying to put a label on the storyboard, and it isn't showing in the simulator

Comment: Are you referring to the title in the navigation bar? Or adding a `UILabel` to the controller?

Comment: I am trying to add the UILabel to the controller

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira That's a separate question and I cannot help over chat because you don't have enough reputation. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081731/how-to-create-uilabel-programmatically-using-swift

Answer (score 2):

use this code in tableview didselect method when we click on cell this method is use for action

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
            vc.strText = "\(arrData[indexPath.row])"
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
             OR
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
```

When we have to pass data or navigation that ViewController is DetailViewController

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var strText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yourlabel.text = strText
    }

}
```

in my code i have used DetailViewController as storyboard id so set that in Storyboard like in SS.

[image]
You can check my video on youtube :-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MOiU_Qop-0

Comment: if this answer is helpful for you then please upvote my answer so other people can find it easily . Thank You